# Should Websphere application server and JRE version used by Eclipse have the exact same version number?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I have trouble while configuring Websphere application server with Eclipse. Is it mandatory to have same JRE version used by Websphere Application SErver and the JRE used by Eclipse?

In my case there is a difference of 0.0 and 0.0.X.

Answer (score 0):

Is not mandatory, but is recommendable update JRE in eclipse,

take a look of this documentation

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/t_install_wdt_sdk.htm